# Reduce array of callback functions to one callback

Tags: javascript, function, underscore.js, reduce

I'm wondering how can I create a function which calls all functions from the array without explicitly creating one. I'm talking about plain javascript (or maybe some underscore.js/lodash helpers, but I haven't found anything useful).

Let's say we have a method which takes a callback:

```
function doSmth(cb) {
  console.log('doing smth');
  cb();
}
```

Now we have three functions which we'd like to call, but we don't like to explicitly create a wrapper function.

```
function write1() {
  console.log(1)
}

function write2() {
  console.log(2)
}

function write3() {
  console.log(3)
}
```

Can we somehow reduce an array of `[write1, write2, write3]` to a single function? I've tried binding `Function.prototype.call` to `Array.prototype.forEach` but I didn't get anywhere.

Edit: I forgot to mention that we don't want to modify `doSmth`

Comment: `_.compose.apply(null, arrOfFns.reverse())();` ought to do it.

Comment: You, sir, are pure genius :) But still it produces f(g(h())), which would mess with arguments, wondering if there's a way to call it f();g();h();

Comment: `arr.reduce((p, x) => (() => { p(); x(); }), () => {})` in es6

Comment: @Selenir in that case see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forEach` with a little helper function.

```
let invoke = (fn, ...args) => fn(...args);
arr.forEach(invoke);

// or for an array of the results
let results = arr.map(invoke);

// es5 translation of invoke
var invoke = function() {
  var fn = arguments[0];
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1, arguments.length);
  return fn.apply(null, args);
};

let doIt = arr.forEach.bind(arr, invoke)
takesACallback(doIt);
```

Comment: Okay but this simply invokes each function in a loop. I can't pass it as a callback to `doSmth`, can I?

Comment: @Selenir see my update. Realize you didn't want a wrapper, but hopefully you see how something generic like my invoke and extractethod functions have broader applicability.

Comment: `arr.map.bind(arr)` produces an error, but `arr.forEach.bind(arr, invoke)` seems to work perfectly. You can edit your answer for future readers. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is simple to do without a 3rd party library. You can pass all the functions you want ran as your callback in the `doSmth` function into a different function first that returns a function that loops through all the callbacks:

```js
function doSmth(cb) {
  console.log('doing smth');
  cb();
}

function write1() {
  console.log(1)
}

function write2() {
  console.log(2)
}

function write3() {
  console.log(3)
}

function mergeManyCallbacks() {
  var fns = Array.from(arguments);
  return function() {
    fns.forEach(fn => {
      fn()
    })
  }
}

// here is your call to doSmth
doSmth(mergeManyCallbacks(write1, write2, write3))
```